# How to play media with my own media player as default

Tags: java, android, video, media, rtsp

I am an Android developer. I've developed a media player that can play both local and streaming videos. But there is a problem. When I click a local media in the gallery how can I configure it to be played with my player? At least, there should be a list of media players including mine one and I should be able to choose it from this list. After succeeding this, I want to open rtsp protocoled files with my player as default. How can I do this? Waiting for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called an Intent Filter. Specifically, you want to set up an intent filter on the type of media you are playing, a data type intent filter. There is more information on this in the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html).